# PHP Loop through values of multi-dimensional array and output as <td></td>

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array that I need to loop through and create `<td></td>` for each value of the inner array.  Can someone show me how to do it?  Thanks.  Here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => I
            [2] => S
        )

    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => S
        )

)
```

I need to retrieve the C, I, and S values.  Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141590/printing-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-table-using-for-loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that your data is validly stored in `$dates` and we want an HTML table with new row for each date:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach( $dates as $date ) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach( $date as $value ) {
    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

For details, see: http://codepad.org/TbfuR2ud

Comment: Looks like you got in there first with that... +1

Comment: Thanks guys.  You make it look so easy!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array as $date) {
  foreach ($date as $val) {
    echo "<td>$val</td>\n";
  }
}
```

You may want to echo some `<tr>`s in the outer loop, to separate them into rows.