# PHP retrieve value from inner array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I retrieve the value of 1 from the following array:

```
Array
(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array
        (
            [C] => 2
            [I] => 1
        )

    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array
        (
            [C] => 2
        )

)
```

Thank you.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-85

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Loop through values of multi-dimensional array and output as <td></td>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295917/php-loop-through-values-of-multi-dimensional-array-and-output-as-td-td)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$value = $yourArray['Nov 18, 2011']['I'];
```